# What would the opposite of "orthopedic" be?

Tags: neologisms

So, I'm wondering, what could the opposite of "orthopedic" be? More precisely, if a force is "orthopedic" in nature (so it would give a correct posture), what would a force that causes bad posture/bad bones position be called?

The closest I could come up with would be "skoliopedic", but that sounds like something that would be specifically about the spine/a twisted change.

I'm looking for something more general, which would mean "crooked bones" or something among those lines. "Kurtopedic" (from kurtosis) could also be an option, but again it seems to address more a twisted/curved shape than a generic badly-shaped/badly-positioned one.

Comment: So you've checked that there isn't an existing (medical) term for this?

Comment: *unergonomic* isn't in most dictionaries, but you can find it in plenty of places. Ergonomic has a wider meaning than orthopedic, but it may well be the closest in common use.

Answer (score 1):

There's a hypernym that is not too global/general, **deformative**.

> **deform** 1 [verb (used with object)]
>
> to mar the natural form or shape of; put out of shape; disfigure
> (...)

[[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/deform)]

..................

> **deformative** [adjective]: tending to deform

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deformative)]